# Using mockito to test methods which throw uncaught custom exceptions

Tags: java, mockito, custom-exceptions

How do I write a Mockito-based JUnit method to test this method `adduser()`? I tried writing one, but it's failing with an error message saying exception is not handled. The error is displayed for:

```
when(service.addUser("nginx")).thenReturn("apache");
```

Assume `addUser()` method in business class never catches any exception and rethrowing is not done.

```
class Business {
    public User addUser() throws ServiceException{
        User user = service.addUser("nginx");
        return user;
    }
}
```

TEST CASE METHOD :

Here in the test class I am mocking the service layer class with `@Mock` attribute and injecting it.

```
@Mock
Service service;   

@InjectMocks
Business business = new Business();

@Test
public void testAddUser() {
    when(service.addUser("nginx")).thenReturn("apache");    
    User user = business.addUser("nginx");
    assertNotNull(user);
}
```

Please tell me how to handle the exception scenario in the test case.

Comment: Are you aware that all that you're testing is that the method returns something not null.  I think you ought to assert that it returns "apache", because you really need to check that `service.addUser()` has actually been called.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Declare the exception in the test method.

```
public void testAddUser() throws ServiceException {
...
}
```

Comment: I have a method which can throw 11 different exceptions (it's an 3rd party dependency), so the list of thrown exceptions get ridiculously long. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: I have got into the habit of just writing `throws Exception` on all my JUnit methods.  There is literally no reason not to, as the JUnit framework catches and reports on anything that you don't catch.  @Olov