# Mockito: mock method throws exception

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to mock this method:

```
boolean login() throws SftpModuleException;
```

Mocking code is:

```
Mockito
    .when(this.sftpService.login())
    .thenReturn(true);
```

Since, `login()` throws an `SftpModuleException`, compiler tells me that this exception has to be handled.

Is there any work around due to this exception will never be thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using mockito to test methods which throw uncaught custom exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238702/using-mockito-to-test-methods-which-throw-uncaught-custom-exceptions)

Answer (score 8):

Consider having your `@Test` method simply declare the exceptions being thrown, or even declaring `throws Exception`.

```
@Test
public void testFoo() throws Exception {
  // mocking and test code here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can add this to a method signature

```
@Test
public void test() throws SftpModuleException {

  Mockito
    .when(this.sftpService.login())
    .thenReturn(true);
  // code
}
```